# jQuery script isn't posting to database

Tags: jquery

This is a jQuery script I'm working on to post inputs to a database, assuming the user submitting the data is logged in, and hasn't made an existing entry for the item the user is submitting data for.

Currently it's not producing any results, and I'm not entirely sure why since I don't work with jQuery that often.

Here is a flow chart illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

```
function csv_three_script() {
    //Include Javascript library
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'csv3', 
        plugins_url( 
            '/js/demo.js', 
            __FILE__ 
        ), 
        array( 
            'jquery'
        )
     );
     wp_localize_script(
     'csv3',
     'MyAjax', array(
     'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'csv_three_script' );



function check_db(){
global $table;
global $quanid;
$hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT count( 1 ) FROM $table WHERE ItemID = '$quanid' AND user = '$hf_userid'", ARRAY_A));
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_db', 'check_db');

function update_entry(){
global $quanid;
$price = isset($_POST[$quanid]);
$hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
global $table;
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prepare( '$table',
    array(
        'ItemID' => '$quanid',
        'Price' => $price,
        'user' => $hf_userid)));

}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_entry', 'update_entry');


function post_entry(){
global $quanid;
$price = isset($_POST[$quanid]);
$hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prepare( 
    '$table', 
    array( 
        'ItemID' => '$quanid',
        'Price'  => $price,
        'user'   => $hf_userid
    ), 
    array( 
        '%d', '%d', '%d'
    ) 
));
die();
return true;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_post_entry', 'post_entry');
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        action: 'is_user_logged_in'
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if (response == 'yes') {
                // user is logged in
                jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                        data: {
                            "action": "check_db",
                            "user": user,
                            "ItemID": ItemID
                        },
                        function(data) {
                            if (data.exists) {
                                //existing entry found, update entry
                                function UpdateRecord(id) {
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: MyAjax
                                            .ajaxurl,
                                        data: {
                                            "action": "update_entry",
                                            "ItemID": ItemID,
                                            "Price": Price,
                                            "user": user
                                        },
                                        success: function(
                                            response
                                        ) {
                                            alert
                                                (
                                                    "Price successfully submitted."
                                                );
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            } else {
                                //existing entry not found, create new entry
                                jQuery("#submit").click(
                                    function() {
                                        var name = jQuery(
                                            "#ItemID").val();
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: MyAjax
                                                .ajaxurl,
                                            data: {
                                                "action": "post_entry",
                                                "ItemID": ItemID,
                                                "Price": Price,
                                                "user": user
                                            },
                                            success: function(
                                                response
                                            ) {
                                                alert
                                                    (
                                                        "Price successfully submitted."
                                                    );
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                            });
                    }
                }, 'JSON');
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
            alert("You must be logged in to submit prices.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's the PHP that is supposed to be attached to this? The php does the database submissions, not the jquery.

Comment: PHP added to question.

Comment: [variable expansion does not occur in single-quoted strings](http://php.net/language.types.string)

Comment: Which part of my code are you referring to? I'd like some clarity.

Comment: `'$table'` and `'$quanid'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use globals :( whenever you think that you need to use a global you should automatically stop coding and invest as much time as it takes to remove that need.

In your case it seems like you assume that global variables persist between Ajax request, but they don't. In addition your design of the code is broken as in client server configuration you can not assume that the server state remain the same between request, therefor when you need to do some operation you need to do it in one request and not to split it into 3. It is good design to let the user know that he can not perform an operation, but you need to actually recheck all conditions when getting to actually performing the operation even if you checked them when you displayed the UI to the user.

Comment: As far as I knew, this was one request as opposed to three. Then again as I stated in my question, I don't work with jQuery that often so I'm not privy to what you're talking about in terms of understanding how to modify my code, I only understand it in a very vague theoretical way.

Comment: I do no not intend to troll you, but if you don't understand my answer then you need to step back and invest several hours in understanding how ajax works in theory on both client and server side, even before addressing jQuery or wordpress specific issues.

Comment: The person who flagged this as low quality, please **explain why**.

Comment: This answer amounts to RTFM, which I could have done on my own. It vaguely explains what I need to do, rather than addressing my specific question.

There are no links to any helpful tutorial sites, no editing of my code, etc; void of what is standard boiler plate on any SE community.

Comment: @Kreation Please note that more general _are_ considered fine here. This answer _does_ point out very specific issue you are having (using globals and general request design). You are not _owed_ for someone to rewrite and fix your code. If people only have time for more general answer, they still _spend that time to try help you_, please appreciate that.

Comment: @Rarst At no point in my post did I ever indicate or think that I was owed anything by anyone. I am simply a little frustrated with this code not working and to receive an answer such as this results in more frustration rather than solutions. 

Regardless, it hasn't helped me other than vaguely indicating to me what is wrong, rather than remedying it - and that is a fact regardless of my state of mind.

Comment: @Kreation just pointing out that you remarks and flagging the question did come across like that a bit. As a moderator I want to point out is that flagging is meant to be used for _serious_ moderation issues, requiring immediate action. Answer not being helpful enough, in your opinion, is not quite an issue for moderators to deal with.